# Hosting a staging/test application parallel/inside hosted application in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, web-applications, codeigniter-2

I have a codeigniter appliation that is hosted on the root like **www.domainname.com**
Now my client wants to have a staging/testing instance of the same in a subfolder like **www.domainname.com/beta**. Need to now to go about this iff it is, at all, possible?

Thanking in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set base url in your config file.

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.domainname.com/beta"
```

Then you can use as usual.

Comment: Ok. so what i understand is that if i copy the application inside beta folder and then update its config file then it should work? Wouldnt .htaccess try to restrict my direct access to beta folder?

Comment: Yes. For htaccess, I think you have to do some changes.

Comment: have you fixed issue?

Comment: Not yet, trying to catch up with changing requirements. Will update the status asap!  :)

Comment: I finally got it working. I created a new folder on root and mapped ny beta site url to that "http://beta.domain.com". 

Copied the entire application within this folder along with .htaccess file. Updated the config and bingo, its working!